# WEKA LibSVM weight parameter for cost

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, svm, libsvm

I am using LibSVM to train  SVM on a highly imbalanced data set. 10% of the output is true while 90% is false. I read about weight parameter:

```
  -wi weight: set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
```

What should be the parameter set for each of the class? What does this weight parameter mean intuitively and how should we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weight parameter controls the skewedness of the SVM optimisation. That is, classes with a higher weight will count more. If the weight for a class is 3 times as much as for another, an instance of the class of the lower weight can be 3 times as far away from the boundary between the classes that libsvm determines as an instance of the other class to get the same optimisation value.

How you use this is entirely up to you -- you could set it such that the two classes are equally weighted (i.e. a weight of 9 for true), but if the results you get with this actually improve on using the same weights is a different matter.

I'd suggest that you play around with different weights to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does it mean the following? Suppose I have an imbalanced data set with Class 1 having far too many samples than Class 2. Now, if I choose the weight parameter for Class 2 to be 3 times than Class 1, I was thinking the hyperplane should actually be more towards Class 1. Your explanation says that it is going to be more towards the minority class, i.e. Class 1. Can you please confirm?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice there are all sorts of other considerations involved -- separating the classes with a hyperplane might not give a clear separation for example. That's why I said that you should try different parameters and see what happens.